# Change Property Value Prior to Page Redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, properties

This is my second asp.net application. In the first application I relied on query to pass values between pages. It worked well, but I found it cumbersome and did not like the long URLs. I was hoping to rely on properties for this application, but I've run in to a problem that I'm not sure how to deal with.

I have two image buttons on the page which redirect to the same page, but should pass different values depending on which button was clicked. I tried to use the OnClick event to set the value of a public property prior to the page redirect. This did not work because PreviousPage.{property} threw a null pointer exception. I am forced to use the PostBackUrl to access PerviousPage properties, but this means I can't change the value of the property in the OnClick event. What do to?

How can I redirect to the same page from two different image buttons, then make the determination in the new page which button was clicked without sending a value in the URL?

Comment: You could set a session variable or use JavaScript to call the page with values. Or you could open the new page as a modal.  Lots of choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public property value is lost if you reload, postback or leave the page. If you set such value during page life cycle it is only available until that cycle ends (it ends when page is fully rendered in the browser).

In OnClick event for each button, before redirection do that:

```
Session.Add("AnyNameHere", "valueWithButtonSpecificData");
```

Then on the page you redirect to read value like that:

```
   if (Session["AnyNameHere"] != null) 
      string s = Session["AnyNameHere"].ToString();
```

Comment: I quite like wrapping my session access in a get/set property. Looks nicer ;) Something a little like `public string MyProperty { get { if(Session["mySessionVar"] != null) { return Session["mySessionVar"].ToString(); } else { return null } }; set { Session["mySessionVar"] = value; } }`

Comment: Session variables! I forgot all about those from my PHP days. That was years ago. Thanks!